# How can I make a table row wrap to the next line when window is small

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make these table cells wrap to the next line when the window is too small to show them all, but I can't get them to break the line when I resize. Any idea how to do it?

```html
<TD>
  <DIV id="mytabs">
    <TABLE height=10 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 bgColor=#ffffff border=0>
      <TBODY>
        <TR>
       <TD class="whitetabs tabBorder" noWrap><A style="CURSOR: hand"><SPAN>&nbsp;&nbsp;blocks1blocks1</SPAN></A></TD>
       <TD class="whitetabs tabBorder" noWrap><A style="CURSOR: hand"><SPAN>&nbsp;&nbsp;tab1</SPAN></A></TD>
       <TD class="whitetabs tabBorder" noWrap><A style="CURSOR: hand"><SPAN>&nbsp;&nbsp;LongNoNameNoBreakTabThree</SPAN></A></TD>
       <TD class="whitetabs tabBorder" noWrap><A style="CURSOR: hand"><SPAN>&nbsp;&nbsp;tab3letters</SPAN></A></TD>
       <TD class="whitetabs tabBorder" noWrap><A style="CURSOR: hand"><SPAN>&nbsp;&nbsp;tab4 </SPAN></A></TD>
       <TD class="whitetabs tabBorder" noWrap><A style="CURSOR: hand"><SPAN>&nbsp;&nbsp;long tab 5</SPAN></A></TD>
       <TD class="whitetabs tabBorder" noWrap><A style="CURSOR: hand"><SPAN>&nbsp;&nbsp;tab6
       <TD>
         <SELECT align=center> 
        <OPTION>&gt;&gt;Select a tab</OPTION> 
      </SELECT>
       </TD>
     </TR>
      </TBODY>
    </TABLE>
  </DIV>
</TD>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8jzc5exd/

Comment: You can try using `display: block` on all table tags, and then apply CSS to achieve the desired outcome you may be looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use media queries to change the table layout altogether.

**Your Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/3jqp7rtt/**

Try resizing the results pane to a smaller width and then back to see how table splits the cells down.

**Snippet**:

```css
table { border: 1px solid #aaa; border-collapse: collapse; }
td { border: 1px solid #aaa; padding: 4px; }

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  tr {display: block; }
  td {display: inline-block; word-break: break-all; }
}
```

```html
<DIV id=tabs>
  <TABLE>
    <TBODY>
      <TR>
        <TD class="whitetabs tabBorder" noWrap><A><SPAN>&nbsp;&nbsp;blocks1blocks1</SPAN></A></TD>
        <TD class="whitetabs tabBorder" noWrap><A><SPAN>&nbsp;&nbsp;tab1</SPAN></A></TD>
        <TD class="whitetabs tabBorder" noWrap><A><SPAN>&nbsp;&nbsp;LongNoNameNoBreakTabThree</SPAN></A></TD>
        <TD class="whitetabs tabBorder" noWrap><A><SPAN>&nbsp;&nbsp;tab3letters</SPAN></A></TD>
        <TD class="whitetabs tabBorder" noWrap><A><SPAN>&nbsp;&nbsp;tab4 </SPAN></A></TD>
        <TD class="whitetabs tabBorder" noWrap><A><SPAN>&nbsp;&nbsp;long tab 5</SPAN></A></TD>
        <TD class="whitetabs tabBorder" noWrap><A><SPAN>&nbsp;&nbsp;tab6</SPAN></A></TD>
        <TD>
          <SELECT align=center> 
            <OPTION>&gt;&gt;Select a tab</OPTION> 
          </SELECT>
        </TD>
      </TR>
    </TBODY>
  </TABLE>
</DIV>
```

**Caution**: While it may seem to work well for a single row table, multiple rows and colspans and nested table structure will just break apart! And of course the semantics get butchered. You've been warned.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, table rows cannot be wrapped themselves, but what you can do is wrap the content within the table cells using css like so:

```
table {
   table-layout: fixed;
   word-break: break-all;
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

If you're open to using a library, you can also look into Bootstrap's responsive table structures. It basically helps you resize the table cells to fit the screen. Read here: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/tables/#responsive-tables

HTH